# Помогите сделать autoscroll в wxWidgets!

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

В wxPanel есть wxFlexGridSizer в котором два wxStatiсText один из которых может безпредельно менять свою длину. Как мне сделать так чтоб в зависимости от длины содержимого появлялся Scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю, вместо `wxStatiсText` использовать `wxTextCtrl` - его стилями можно сделать неотличимым от `wxStaticText`, сделать его read-only + многострочным (это все в тех же стилях). И тогда он сам будет автоматически создавать полосу прокрутки, когда надо (опять же, регулируется стилями - её можно сделать перманентной).

Comment: Но как в него втычить ентер?

Comment: Установить стиль "многострочный". У меня для таких целей стоят стили (из wxSmith): wxTE_MULTILINE, wxTE_READONLY, wxTE_RICH2, wxSTATIC_BORDER. Правда. при этом скролл вроде есть перманентно. Чтобы он прятался, наверное, надо еще какую-то опцию. Кажется, `wxTE_AUTO_SCROLL`.